# How to browse questions from all of my communities?

Tags: support

I've only recently started participating in Stack Exchange, and I was wondering if there's a way to browse questions from all of my communities at the same time. When I created my account I envisioned being able to browse questions with a similar functionality to how Reddit's frontpage works for logged-in users.

The Stack Exchange homepage is kind of how I imagined it, but it shows 'hot' questions from *all* Stack Exchange sites instead of just the communities I have joined.

How can I view question from sites in which I have an account on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com) and click on **filtered questions**.

[image]

Choose **my sites** option and it will show questions where you've an account on.

[image]

Comment: Duh, I think I may be missing some brain cells :P Makes total sense. Thanks for the answer!